# All content without scrolling vs content scrollable on home page

Tags: scrolling, homepage, screen-resolution

For one, if you want all your content shown without scrolling, your site will end up being saturated.
For the second option, you don't have to worry on spacing issues and you can make your design breathe a lot more, but you have the risk that the user doesn't scroll and won't see everything he wants to see.

Which option is the best?

Comment: It really depends on what kind of website it is. Is it one of consumption, where the user is browsing through a gallery or articles? Or is it a marketing site where the user needs to be educated on what the site is and what the product benefits are before the call to action? The approach you take is based on the utility and goals

Comment: UX myth #3 - People don't scroll http://uxmyths.com/post/654047943/myth-people-dont-scroll

Comment: Given that you can't control the screan size, how can you hope to never have scrooling contect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the "above the fold" area to tease. Make sure the user knows what it's about in one fell swoop (a couple of WORDS, not LINES) so they can decide on whether your product might be worth a look **then and there**. If you need 2 pages to tell your user about your product, you're doing it wrong.

If the user thinks it's something he needs, he'll WORK for information. And by work, I don't even mean scrolling, because scrolling isn't a barrier anymore. It might have been back in the early nineties, but that's way behind us.

Comment: Thank, your answer is more of what I'm looking for. Is there any good source can backup what you are saying? Because that would be really helpful

Comment: I don't know if this is considered a valid source, but have a look here:
http://uxmyths.com/post/654047943/myth-people-dont-scroll